# How to make CSS of lightning bundle dynamic

Tags: lightning-aura-components, security, css, security-review

I have a component used in my org from [lightning strike](http://www.lightningstrike.io/). This component uses innerHTML property of  element to assign css classes. The code is as follows:

> Markup:

```
<style aura:id="tooltipStyle"></style>
```

> Controller:

```
calculateTooltipPosition: function(component) {
    //Some code
            adjustment = Math.abs(containerLeft + tooltipXPos) + 4;
            tooltipStyle.innerHTML = '.st-popover_container .slds-nubbin--top:before { transform: translateX(' + -adjustment + 'px) rotate(45deg); } .st-popover_container .slds-nubbin--top:after { transform: translateX(' + -adjustment + 'px) rotate(45deg); }';
        } 
    //Some more code

    return {
        tooltipXPos : tooltipXPos,
        tooltipYPos : tooltipYPos,
        width : tooltipWidth
    }
}
```

In salesforce security review, it gives error for "innerHTML" code. How can this be avoided?

I am thinking of adding CSS class like :

> CSS:

```
.THIS.st-popover_container .slds-nubbin--top:before 
{ 
    transform: translateX(' + -adjustment + 'px) rotate(45deg); 
}

.THIS.st-popover_container .slds-nubbin--top:after {
    transform: translateX(' + -adjustment + 'px) rotate(45deg);
}
```

But the problem is how to fetch value of "adjustment" dynamically as it is calculated runtime.

Comment: You'll want to [create a custom renderer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_renderers.htm) in your component to set the style on the element after rendering. Do not use innerHTML in Lightning, because yes, it does violate security design. You'll need to read a few topics in the Lightning Component Developer Guide related to custom rendering.

Comment: What do you need? I think you CAN use innerHTML, CSP allow it if no external resource modify your dom. But you CAN’T modify CSS Component from JS. You need to update style property of HTML element

Comment: @Edu Trujillo: We've got messages from security review that innerHTML is not allowed. I will post the exact message once I get to work tomorrow. I guess I'll try sfdcfox's suggestion and get back to you guys.